# Reversing a txt document using stacks

Tags: c++, stack, character, reverse

Okay so I'm writing a relatively simple program that takes the characters from a txt document pops them from a stack and saves them to a second file but in reverse order such as:

> hello there!
>
> !ereht olleh

I have a bit of code and I have been tweaking it but it does not execute correctly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
include <stack>

using namespace std;

void reverse(ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile);  //function prototype

void main () 
{

ifstream infile;  // declaring a file for input
ofstream outfile; // declaring a file for output
infile.open ("myInputFile.txt"); 

 if (!infile) 
 { cout << "File could not be opened." << endl;
 }

 outfile.open ("myOutfile.txt");

 reverse (infile, outfile);

infile.close();// Close both files
outfile.close();


system("pause");
}

void reverse (ifstream & infile, ofstream & outfile) 
{
string s;
stack<string> mystack;

 getline(infile, s); // try to read a line of text from the file

 while (getline(infile, s)) // while not end of file
 { 
     mystack.push(s);
     getline(infile, s); // try to read another line

 }
 while (!mystack.empty())
 {
     s = mystack.top();
     outfile << s << endl; // write s to the outfile
     mystack.pop();
 }


 }
```

EDIT: Sorry I forgot the most important part.. the problem. When the program executes It doesn't do anything to the output file. So that leads me to believe it's in my logic around the reverse part.

EDIT: EDIT: okay, I've been messing around and i still can't get it to do exactly what, it now prints to the output file but it just takes what is in line 2 and puts it in line 1.

Example: input file:

`Hello world
 How are things`

output file: `How are things`

My desired output would either be all of the characters reversed or even just the word orders reversed.

Example
"dlrow olleh" or
"world Hello"

Sorry this is my first post, but i'm trying to find help.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: It could be an idea to describe the problem.

Comment: You aren't removing the strings from the stack. Use `mystack.pop()` to do that. BTW, you mean to test `!infile` to see if the file didn't open. (And just saying "program terminated" doesn't actually terminate the program!)

Comment: @ooga Thanks! tweaking it right now. Also I knew it wasn't going to terminate it, after I got the program to run correctly i was going to add in a simple y/n loop to retry. and i just got a little ahead of myself. Thanks for the quick reply guys. sorry about the problem part >Cheers and hth. -alf

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help @ooga. The pop stack set me on the right track although that wasn't my problem.

I realized i was using a string stack when i should have been using a Char stack to do what i wanted and get my desired output.

Program works great now.

-Titan